# Use section index in .nsh header file?

Tags: indexing, nsis

As the question says: I´m trying to use the section index in a .nsh file which configures pages and includes custom pages.
I´m trying to do so with the function SectionSetInstTypes.

When I try to get the INST Type with SectionGetInstTypes it´s not working the output is always 7.

This is my code in the header file for the inst type:

*SectionSetInstTypes ${Section2} 1
SectionGetInstTypes ${Section2} $R4
messagebox mb_ok "$R4"*

Is there no or any possibility to get the index in the .nsh files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSIS does not really care if the code is in a .nsh or your main .nsi but a section index is only valid after the section!

```
Section
SectionGetText ${mysec} $0 ;will generate compiler warning
DetailPrint $0 ;$0 is ""
SectionEnd

Section "Hello" mysec
SectionEnd

Section
SectionGetText ${mysec} $0
DetailPrint $0
SectionEnd
```

So your sections need to be above your !include in your .nsi...

Comment: Thanks haven´t thought about that! But that makes it more difficult changing the InstType while Runtime. A Flag will do the work :)